# Is there an up-to-date Facebook Java SDK?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-api, facebook-java-sdk

I can't seem to find one that's been updated recently.  If none, is there a good Java library for doing the necessary signature verification, base64 decoding, etc operations needed to interact with Facebook's API?

***UPDATE***: I'm using [Spring Social Facebook](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) to aid in working with Facebook.  It doesn't handle everything and isn't perfect, but the best library out there for Java.  Looking forward to the ongoing progress from Spring.  I asked a couple questions in their forum and responses were informative and super quick.

Comment: I don't like using Spring. If feels like if you use just one thing of theirs - everything else they have gets shoved in your throat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check facebook's official android SDK which is written in Java:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

all basic things like verification, decoding, etc are there, maybe android-related stuff is not what you need but I guess it is relatively trivial to extract it from there.

hope this helps

Comment: i think this do not work with web applications.

Comment: Is this compiles with just a JDK (not Android)?

Answer (score 5):

I just started using [RestFB](http://restfb.com/). I looked at Spring first, but this seems like RestFB has a gentler learning curve. I'll update if it works for me.

Comment: It worked fine for me back when I was working on a Facebook project (roughly Oct 11 - Apr 12).

Answer (score 2):

i think the semi-official java SDK is the spring social one:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-social

but i wrote a Java wrapper for Facebook's REST GRAPH API
(http calls to the graph api, and translations from json objects to java classes..)

you can check it out here:

https://github.com/itzikrou/fishbowl

hope it's usefull..

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/roundrop/facebook4j looks nice but haven't yet used it.

For example, the search API look straightforward:

```
ResponseList<User> results = facebook.searchUsers("mark");
ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.searchPosts("watermelon");
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to developers.facebook.com , there u will get all API's releated to facebook..also manual regarding how to use them...

Comment: And, of course, no Java APIs, unless you have a link to one?