# java application share option

Tags: java, social-networking, share

I've been developing a [photo browsing app](http://i39.tinypic.com/2lddls4.png) and I was wondering if maybe there is some kind of way to add some social-networking options to it( like sharing one or more photos on facebook or twitter, etc.). Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are such options, take a look at:

- [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)
- [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media)

Comment: I've used Facebook Graph but only on mobile platforms. Are you sure I can use it within my desktop app?

Comment: Take a look at this question, seems like something doable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470157/is-there-an-up-to-date-facebook-java-sdk

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll take a look later at those sdk's.